# unable to create array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am bit new to object oriented programming using javascript.

I have an array of workspace as

```
//global var
var workspaceArray = new Array();
```

then I am pushing a workspace object in the array as -

```
//in some function
workspaceArray.push(new wsObj());

//wsObj function
function wsObj(){
    states = new Array();
    links = new Array();
}
```

But when I try to use it somewhere it throws error that cannot read property state.

```
//error in the following line
var stateName = "q" + "<sub>" + workspaceArray[activeWSId].states.length + "</sub>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is 'activeWSId'?

Comment: check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Pz7R/

Comment: Thanks Anand, I got the issue, it was the missing this keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `states` and `links` as global variables, instead of assigning them to the created Object. Assign them like like this

```
//wsObj function
function wsObj(){
    this.states = new Array();
    this.links = new Array();
}
```

And it will work!

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually I read this one tutorial but missed this keyword :(.